# SMOTE resampling produces nan values

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, smote

I am using SMOTE to oversample the minority of a dataset. My code is as follows:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_coded, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42, sampling_strategy='all')
# also tried the following, same result
# sm = SMOTE(random_state=42, sampling_strategy=0.5)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

I check features_coded, labels, X_train and y_train using statements like the following:

```
features_coded[features_coded.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

I am pretty sure that they do not contain any nan values before oversampling. However, after resampling, there are a lot of nan values in the X_train dataframe.

Just in case you are wondering:
This is my dataframe (saved as csv file) before oversampling, nothing is missing.
[image: My dataset before oversampling]

This is my dataframe (saved as csv file) after oversampling, a lot of empty values!
[image: The same dataset after oversampling]

Is anything wrong?

Comment: [salvolapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15025968) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65765456) saying "SMOTE and many of its variants except RandomOverSampler can't handle categorical values. Is that your case? https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/over_sampling.html#smote-variants"

Comment: I guess not and I found an ugly hack to avoid it: If I save dataframe to a csv file and then read the file to dataframe again, the issue will disappear. I think it is about the internal structure of dataframe rather than the SMOTE package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SMOTE algorithm for oversampling in Python and it is producing null values. You can fix this issue by following these steps:

**1. Check Data Formatting:** Make sure each column of the dataset (i.e., df) is properly formatted with the correct data type. e.g., categorical features must have dtype="category".

**2. Fix Incorrect implementation:** Ensure that you are using a proper implementation of SMOTE for multiclass data. *SMOTE was originally designed for binary classification*, but there are extensions available for multi-class scenarios like SMOTE-NC, Borderline-SMOTE, etc.

***Here I show an example of using SMOTE-NC which is better when you have Nominal and Continuous features & multi-class labels in the dataset:***

```
# import SMOTE-NC
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC

# mention index of categorical features
cat_feats = [2, 3, 4, 7, 11]

# initialize and apply SMOTENC
smotenc = SMOTENC(categorical_features=cat_feats, random_state=42)
X_sm, y_sm = smotenc.fit_resample(X, y)

# verify imbalance problem fixed
print(y_sm.value_counts())

# verify no null values produced by SMOTE
print(X_sm.isna().sum())
print(y_sm.isna().sum())
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue, I converted my inputs `X` and `Y` as arrays using the lines `X_arr = numpy.array(X)` and `y_arr = numpy.array(Y)` and fed them to `train_test_split()` as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_arr, y_arr, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2)

smote = SMOTE(random_state=2)

X_train_balanced, Y_train_balanced = smote.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```